# How to know if blue dot is within visible portions of my mapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am working with MKMapView. When the user scrolls the map in a way that blue dot indicating user's current location disappears from his sight, tapping a button on mapView brings him back to the portion that contains that blue dot. I am doing it simply by setting

```
 self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
```

on button's action method.
But I have to change button's image once he scrolls away from blue dot. So, how would I know if blue dot is not in the portions of the map that is currently visible to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a delegate to the map view, `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:`, so that you are informed when a scroll event has occurred.

In your implementation of that method you can get the `visibleMapRect` and use `MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect` to get the associated real world coordinates of the map view. You can then determine if the current user location is visible (this requires a simple calculation, I don't think there's a built in method).

Comment: just one final question. My blue dot turns gray sometimes on selecting some other annotation and sometimes on tapping mapView. How can I retain its blue colour?

Comment: what delegate methods have you implemented (this is a new question really)

Comment: viewForAnnotation, didSelectAnnotationView, didUpdateUserLocation, regionDidChangeAnimated. In viewForAnnotation I  am returning nil if (annotation == mapView.userLocation). In didSelectAnnotationView before changing annotation image I do check if((MKAnnotationView.annotation == mapView.userLocation)).

Comment: best to create a new question and show all that code properly

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in boolean flag `self.mapView.userLocationVisible`

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
//do something here
 if(self.mapView.userLocationVisible){
   //Blue dot visible
 }
 else{
   //Blue dot hidden
 }
//do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in code:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    if (MKMapRectContainsPoint(self.mapView.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate))) {
        NSLog(@"blue dot visible");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"blue dot not visible");
    }
}
```